# I have been trying to compare a variable,it has multiple values in jmeter using beanshell assertion but as the values are in jumbled order it fails

Tags: json, jmeter

I am new to jmeter and learning it.

I have taken two different server names,both the servers has the same values and variables,they are almost identical

I need to compare deviceId so I have taken it using json extractor by $..deviceId and have given match no -1 and check the box suffix_ALL, did this for deviceId and other_deviceId

I have given the beanshell assertion as
[image]

When I run it I am getting error because host has deviceid like {1abc,2abc}, where as host1 has deviceid {2abf,1abc}, the values are jumbled but correct.

Is there any way that we can compare in such situations so the test case can be passed.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial/)
2. You might want to cast the variables to [Lists](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#Collections-Lists) or [Maps](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#Collections-Maps) using [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) and the collections can be sorted and then compared
3. The easiest way of comparing 2 JSONs is using a 3rd-party library like [JSONAssert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert)